# any-promise doesn't have explicit registration in imported library

Tags: javascript, webpack, mocha.js, babeljs

I am trying to run some tests on a component that I wrote. For some reasons it keep failing with this error:

```
Error: any-promise browser requires a polyfill or explicit registration e.g: require('any-promise/register/bluebird')
```

There is a library that I am using which instantiates Promise like the line below, but it doesn't use any polyfill neither registers the promise explicitly.

```
var Promise = require("any-promise");
```

If I add this line `require('any-promise/register/bluebird')` just before Promise initialization line it all works as expected (should I?).

Is it something I can fix in my project / mocha / babel / webpack setup?

Answer (score 0):

Just found a workaround by replacing `any-promise` module with bluebird which works in my case.

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/^any-promise$/, 'bluebird'),
]
```

Source: [any-promise github issue](https://github.com/kevinbeaty/any-promise/issues/27)